# What does it mean when some of the elements are grey in the console under the 'Elements' tab?

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser, console

I've recently started getting familiar with the console, identifying certain elements through it and such. However, I've stumbled upon this on [Disney's website](https://register.disneylandparis.com/entry-reservation/) and I was wondering why do some of these elements have a grey background? What does that indicate?

[image: elements-tab]

Answer (score 1):

You have the "Show user agent shadow DOM" setting turned on, and these Shadow DOM elements are highlighted in grey.

You can learn about ShadowRoot here: [What is shadow root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34119639/what-is-shadow-root)

And you can learn more about the Shadow DOM here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM