# What is DOMElement.shadowRoot?

Tags: javascript

What is DOMElement.shadowRoot? What does it do? Why does it return null? What can it be used for?

```
document.body.shadowRoot
```

I tried searching but I can't understand what it does.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ShadowRoot

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/shadowRoot

Comment: https://bitsofco.de/what-is-the-shadow-dom/

Comment: The third paragraph in the accepted answer sums it up pretty well, [What is shadow root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34119639/what-is-shadow-root)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a container for the "internal DOM" (i.e. the shadow DOM) of native elements such as `<input>` or `<button>` (or custom elements made with the web components APIs).

When you inspect `<input>` you only see the `<input>` itself:

[image]

But you can turn on a flag in the Chrome Dev Tools to enable the visibility of the shadow DOM:

[image]

You can now see how the `<input>` is "implemented" by the browser. For example the placeholder is contained within a `<div>` element:

[image]