# html not being displayed correctly

Tags: shadow-dom

I have the following html:

```
 <div class='contact section-two'>
      <input class='info' type='email' name='email' placeholder='email' 
      value="">
      <span class='alerts hidden'>Please enter your email</span>
 </div>
```

but when I check developer tools I'm getting:

```
<div class='contact section-two'>
      <input class='info' type='email' name='email' placeholder='email' value="">
          #shadow-root (user-agent)
             <div pseudo="-internal-input-suggested" id="placeholder" 
             style='display:block!important; user-select:none!important;"> 
             abc@gmail.com</div>
             <div></div>
       </input>
      <span class='alerts hidden'>Please enter your email</span>
 </div>



 How do I prevent the shadow-root element?  Also, why the heck is this 
 shadow element being added in the first place?
```

when I run the html on localhost it works fine.  When I run it live on bluehost I get the shadowhost problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is shadow root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34119639/what-is-shadow-root)

Comment: no, not even close

Comment: Have you tried with different browsers? My first guess would be that the browser itself is injecting a custom component on every email input field at runtime. Perhaps because of a plugin. Does it do so only with your app?

Comment: no on other pages it's not doing that.  It seems to only be a problem with chrome

Comment: no on other pages it's not doing that. It works correctly on firefox but not with ms edge or chrome

Comment: @DCR are you able to try with Chrome / MS Edge on a different computer?

Comment: it's not the computer.  It seems to be autofill of passwords and emails from the browsers saved list of passwords being applied to a shadow-root element