# document.getElementById returns null in Chrome Console

Tags: javascript

I know, there were millions of such questions, but I just can't find anything that's helpful :(

Why does `document.getElementById("game")` return `null`, even if the `document` clearly contains such element?

[image]

Comment: Where in your code do you place <script> tag, before or after your html?

Comment: Are there any more game tags? It could be because the game tag is within the <game-app> tag.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34119639/what-is-shadow-root

Comment: @m-s7 Het typed in the console, so it should be found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The element with that ID does not belong to the `document`. It belongs to the [shadow DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM) attached to the `<game-theme-manager>` element.