# Python Selenium - Accept Cookies.click() not working

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, cookies

I tried various methods to click the **Accept cookies button**, but none of them worked.

**Target-URL**: https://www.knvb.nl/ontdek-voetbal/ga-voetballen/vind-een-club

My Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

url = 'https://www.knvb.nl/ontdek-voetbal/ga-voetballen/vind-een-club'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(1)

accept_all_button_link_text = driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "Accept all").click()
time.sleep(1)
```

**Approaches tried:**

```
accept_all_button_xpath = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[@id='cmpbntyestxt']").click()

accept_all_button_span_xpath = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[@id='cmpbntyestxt']/span").click()

cookies_btn_xpath = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(),'Accept all')]").click()

cookies_btn_xpath = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(),'Accepteer alles')]").click()

accept_all_button_id = driver.find_element(By.ID, "cmpbntyestxt").click()

accept_all_button_css_id = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#cmpbntyestxt").click()

accept_all_button_css_class = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".cmpboxbtnyes").click()

accept_all_button_css_class_tag = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.cmpboxbtnyes").click()

accept_all_button_css_attribute = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[id='cmpbntyestxt']").click()

accept_all_button_link_text = driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "Accept all").click()

accept_all_button_partial_link_text = driver.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Accept all").click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

If you notice the above HTML mark-up, your desired element(<kbd>Accept all</kbd> button) is wrapped within a [SHADOW DOM](https://cosmocode.io/how-to-interact-with-shadow-dom-in-selenium/).

Refer the working code below to perform action on Shadow DOM element:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.knvb.nl/ontdek-voetbal/ga-voetballen/vind-een-club")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

allowAll_btn = driver.execute_script("""return document.querySelector('div.cmpwrapper').shadowRoot.querySelector('a.cmpboxbtn.cmpboxbtnyes.cmptxt_btn_yes')""")
allowAll_btn.click()
time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: Thank you; I was unfamiliar with the "shadow element" concept. I appreciate your help 

Answer (score 1):

Its a [Shadow Element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34119639/what-is-shadow-root)

[XPATH in shadow elements](https://www.numpyninja.com/post/how-can-we-find-the-xpath-for-shadow-element#:%7E:text=The%20shadow%20DOM%20can%20identify,from%20the%20actual%20Main%20DOM.)

Try something like

```py
cmpWrapper = driver.find_element_by_id("cmpwrapper") # id of the div container

# Access the shadow root using JavaScript
shadowRoot = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].shadowRoot;", cmpWrapper)

shadowRoot.find_element(...)
```