# Cannot execute click on Accept Cookies button

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm having problem with finding path to click the accept cookies button.
The website I use is [deinhandy.de](https://deinhandy.de).
When I inspect the website I got this

```
<button role="button" data-testid="uc-accept-all-button" class="sc-dcJsrY iigiUZ" style="height: 40px; margin: 0px 6px;">
    Alles Akzeptieren
</button>
```

and its XPATH is

```
//*[@id="uc-center-container"]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/button
```

[Screenshot of the website and inspect section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0rBn.png)

I tried both `find_element` by XPATH and CLASS-NAME but it still doesn't work for me

```
try:
    cookies = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="uc-center-container"]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/button')
    cookies.click()
except:
    print("No cookies accept button found")
```

and

```
try:
    cookies = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'dcJsrY') # even with 'iigiUZ', 'dcJsrY iigiUZ' 'sc-dcJsrY iigiUZ'
    cookies.click()
except:
    print("No cookies accept button found")
```

Comment: let me try this to accept cookie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
If you notice the above HTML mark-up, your desired element <kbd>Alles Akzeptieren</kbd> is wrapped within a [SHADOW DOM](https://cosmocode.io/how-to-interact-with-shadow-dom-in-selenium/).

Check the working code below to handle it:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.deinhandy.de/")
time.sleep(5)
# Access the shadow root using JavaScript and click it
cookie_btn = driver.execute_script("""return document.querySelector('div#usercentrics-root').shadowRoot.querySelector('button.sc-dcJsrY.iigiUZ')""")
cookie_btn.click()
time.sleep(10)
```

Check this answer for similar issue and solution - https://stackoverflow.com/a/77989300/7598774

Comment: I just vote up ...

Comment: Thank you very much, first time I ever heard about Shadow Dom. I appreciate your help a lot.