cannot find button element
I'm trying to subscribe to this reddit page via a click button.
I have opened the page in inspect mode, located the button and copied its XPATH into the code below.
But the code is saying it cannot find the element.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

URL = "https://www.reddit.com/r/learnjavascript"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(URL)
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/div/faceplate-tracker").click()


driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/div/faceplate-tracker").click()


XPath expression is clearly wrong. Relative XPath starts with //. Which element do you want to click?

the "join" button ...

Issues:

XPath expression is incorrect. Few references below for you to read and understand about XPaths.

How to use XPath in Selenium?
XPath in Selenium: All You Need to Know


The target element("Join" button) is within a nested shadow root element. You need to deal with shadow roots first before trying to interact with the target element. Few references below for your info:

Evaluating the Shadow DOM
https://stackoverflow.com/a/78152794/7598774
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76666253/7598774



Check the code below to click on "Join" button:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

URL = "https://www.reddit.com/r/learnjavascript"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(URL)
time.sleep(5)
root1=driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "shreddit-subreddit-header-buttons").shadow_root
root2=root1.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "shreddit-join-button").shadow_root
join_Btn=root2.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[class=' button-primary button-medium button join-btn leading-none px-sm py-xs ']")
join_Btn.click()
time.sleep(10)

Code modified and applied selenium waits to effectively locate elements. Check code below:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

URL = "https://www.reddit.com/r/learnjavascript"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(URL)
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)

root1=wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "shreddit-subreddit-header-buttons"))).shadow_root
root2=WebDriverWait(root1, 15).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "shreddit-join-button"))).shadow_root
join_Btn = WebDriverWait(root2, 15).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[class=' button-primary button-medium button join-btn leading-none px-sm py-xs ']")))
join_Btn.click()

time.sleep(10)


The first time I loaded this code, it said it couldn't find the element ... the other 3 times ... It worked perfectly, thanks ... I took 10 years off coding selenium, sorry my XPATH was clearly wrong ... then new Selenium has come along way since. I've never seen shadow_root

is there like a ... wait function I can introduce before .find_element ... so the page has completely loaded? ... I used to have so much trouble with the DOM always changing

Yes you can use Selenium's waits. Few more links - https://www.browserstack.com/guide/wait-commands-in-selenium-webdriver.

since your code threw a traceback error on the first attempt ... is it worth including a wait function in your accepted answer? (Im not sure if selenium has built-in wait functions, since its eariler versions)

Check the updated answer for new code. Let me know if this consistently works.

Its working, thanks!

How do I snapshot the HTML code with .shadow_root? I tried, driver.page_source ... and ... driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML") ... but they are not showing the shadow root that reveals the BUTTON TEXT ... so i can confirm the word, Joined has now replaced the word Join

Don't think I undersood your question, sorry. I think what you are asking is how to check the HTML of the page to see if Joined button is inside a shadow-root element or not! If that is correct. You can manually inspect the web page. Right click on Joined button --> Click on Inspect option --> At the bottom of the page Elements window will opep up. You can check the entire HTML of the page there.

yeah, I can check the HTML of the button if join_Btn.get_attribute("outerHTML").find("Join\n </button>") == -1: print("SUCCESS!") .... but after join_Btn.click() ... the above code throws a traceback error because it no longer exists (cannot find element) ... which is why I was wanting to know if I could driver.page_source the whole page ... and ask the entire page (including shadow-root) ... if join was clicked and is now called joined

I suggest creating a new question with all the details, that way you will get answer from wider community.

Can you help with a reddit follow button? I can get the shadow root, root1 = Globals.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "follow-button").shadow_root ... this works ... but the click button is not working ... join_Btn = root1.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"[div slot='button-follow']") ... https://www.reddit.com/user/PBTech/

If you look closely, follow button is not inside shadow-root. So, first line is not required. Following line should click on the element. join_Btn = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"span.button-text") join_Btn.click()

join_Btn.click() throws an exception ... element not interactable

Please create new post and ask question, we can't end up flooding comments section here.

Ok, I will create a new post tomorrow. Sorry
