How to know if element is located in iframe?
I'm having trouble locating the element circled in red and believe it may be in a frame. The element:
<button rpl="" class="upload-media action
button-small px-[var(--rem6)]
button-secondary


icon
items-center justify-center
button inline-flex " id="device-upload-button" type="button"> <!--?lit$869276182$--><!----><span class="flex items-center justify-center"> <!--?lit$869276182$--><span class="flex"><!--?lit$869276182$--><svg rpl="" fill="currentColor" height="16" icon-name="upload-outline" viewBox="0 0 20 20" width="16" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"> <!--?lit$869276182$--><!--?lit$869276182$--><path d="m10.513 5.63 3.929 3.928-.884.884-2.933-2.933V19h-1.25V7.51l-2.933 2.932-.884-.884L9.67 5.446l.589-.029.254.212Zm5.859-1.482A6.876 6.876 0 0 0 10 0a6.876 6.876 0 0 0-6.372 4.148A4.639 4.639 0 0 0 0 8.625a4.716 4.716 0 0 0 4.792 4.625V12A3.465 3.465 0 0 1 1.25 8.625 3.412 3.412 0 0 1 4.189 5.31l.364-.06.123-.35A5.607 5.607 0 0 1 10 1.25a5.607 5.607 0 0 1 5.324 3.65l.123.348.364.06a3.412 3.412 0 0 1 2.939 3.317A3.465 3.465 0 0 1 15.208 12v1.25A4.716 4.716 0 0 0 20 8.625a4.639 4.639 0 0 0-3.628-4.477Z"></path><!--?--> </svg></span> <!--?lit$869276182$--> </span> <!--?lit$869276182$--><!--?--><!----><!----><faceplate-screen-reader-content><!--?lit$869276182$-->Upload files</faceplate-screen-reader-content><!----> </button>

I tried:
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.reddit.com/r/Watchexchange/submit/?type=IMAGE")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'device-upload-button')))
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="device-upload-button"]')))
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//button[contains(@class,'flex items-center justify-center')])))

It didn't work, which leads me to think it's in a frame that I need to switch to first. Here's the surrounding html:
surrounding html

I use DevTools in Chome/Firefox to check manually if element is in iframe. But you can always use selenium to find all iframe and use for-loop to switch_to.frame() and check xpath in every iframe

you may also use seslenium to get all <button> and display what classes or ids they use. Maybe server sends you elements with different values.

on image I see #shadow-root - and this can make problem. See javascript - How to automate shadow DOM elements using selenium? - Stack Overflow

I searched for all buttons and found 7 using By.TAG_NAME, 'button', however checking their data, none of them turned out to be the button I was looking for. The button also appears twice in the page so there's 2 elements with the same id=device-upload-button

could you post the html code for button by inspeacting element pls. include 2nd button as well

Targeted element is not within an IFRAME, but it is within a shadow-root element. You can use Javascript to access the elements which are inside shadow-root. Try the below code:
# Access the shadow root using JavaScript and click it
upload_btn = driver.execute_script("""return document.querySelector('r-post-media-input#post-composer_media').shadowRoot.querySelector('button#device-upload-button')""")
upload_btn.click()

Note: I have not tested the above code, as I do not have log-in credentials for Reddit.
References:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/78152794/7598774
https://stackoverflow.com/a/78471405/7598774
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77989300/7598774


No need to execute the shadow_root CSS yourselves anymore:
shadow_root is now supported in all browsers
From the html img I've jotted together something that may work, But I need lots of testing to get it right:
el = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//faceplate-form-section)[3]") # 3rd element
# el = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//faceplate-form-section")[2] # often more solid
el2 = el.shadow_root.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "r-post-media-input") 
el2.shadow_root.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div div div button").click()

Please notice that you can't use XPATH navigation in shadow_root it comes from the execution of javascript. like in @Shawn answer below.
